# ListBox handling in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a list box and a button click event ,when i select an item in the list box and click on the button then the list item should appear in the text box...please help with the code.

```
private void Get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        tb1.Text = listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

but it is not working, I'm getting like this but i just need item name to appear on textbox...

> System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: item name

Comment: What does ToString return? Is it actually giving you a value? What is the type in SelectedItem?

Comment: suppose my item name is stack in listbox ..i'm getting (System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: Stack) in my textbox

Comment: Having you revert my edit does not help my inclination to help. I edited it because I could not read it like this. Others will have the same problem.

Comment: @Gusdor - giving him the benefit of the doubt, it appears you were both editing the post at the same time

Comment: @AndrewShepherd I really need to look at timestamps. -_-

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listbox1.SelectedItem.Content.ToString()
```

`ListBoxes` wrap all content in a `ListBoxItem`, which is what you are seeing. `ListBoxItem` inherits `ContentControl` and therefore has a `Content` property. This contains the object that you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx

Comment: And don't forget to cast Content to your list item data class in case it is not string.